# Can't get Google Map API to appear on my pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a Google Map with multiple markets for a client and I've tried a number of examples, but each time I get a blank white area on my page. I'm integrating this as part of a WordPress theme, but nothing seems to click. I even tried a plugin to no avail. Here's where the problem is:

http://www.aishla.com/blog/2014/

Scroll down to the Contact area and you'll see the blank space. It'll be very obvious.

Should mention I'm aware in my HTML that I'm using the same ID twice. All due to the theme. Deleting it did not get rid of the issue.

Here's the example I found for the embed code. Maybe this is no longer valid?
http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/

Comment: which browser? loads fine for me. (chrome)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me too (on Chrome). You do have some errors in your page though:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined www.aishla.com/blog/2014/wp-content/themes/aish-child/js/stickUp.min.js:1
12Uncaught ReferenceError: vartop is not defined www.aishla.com/blog/2014/wp-content/themes/aish-child/js/stickUp.min.js:1
53Uncaught ReferenceError: vartop is not defined

Comment: Just checked Safari and it's showing up as well. Must be a FF thing.

Comment: Using FF on Windows, your map renders correctly for me. It's just set off to the right by one screen size. Applying `left: -100%` in the FF inspector moved it into the expected position. So I assume this is a CSS issue.

Comment: hennes: which div did you apply that on?